# Recursively parse multiple json objects to practice calculations - Python

Tags: python, json, database

I have to set up an analytical system of a Json data base(Firebase Realtime Database).
Here's what it looks like:

```
{
  "247" : {
    "activity_duration" : 15,
    "battery_used" : 0,
    "date" : "2017-09-05",
    "day" : 247,
    "heat_waves" : 3,
    "outside_temperature" : 16.64,
    "shirt_temperature" : [ 24.883928571428573, 23.660714285714285 ]
  },
  "262" : {
    "activity_duration" : 240,
    "battery_used" : 2,
    "date" : "2017-09-20",
    "day" : 262,
    "heat_waves" : 5,
    "outside_temperature" : 21.19,
    "shirt_temperature" : [ 24.233616504854368, 22.954490291262136 ]
  },
  "268" : {
    "activity_duration" : 260,
    "battery_used" : 5,
    "date" : "2017-09-26",
    "day" : 268,
    "heat_waves" : 4,
    "outside_temperature" : 16.07,
    "shirt_temperature" : [ 18.68695652173913, 17.576630434782608 ]
  }
}
```

To do this, I want to practice calculations in python on my json file like the average of `heat_waves`.

The problem is that I can not access the nodes without writing them in raw.
`data["247"]["heat_waves"]` but I want something like `data[0]["heat_waves"]`.When I try:

```
import json;

data = [ ];
filename = "Database.json";
with open(filename,'r') as json_data:
     data = json.load(json_data);
     print(json.dumps(data[0]["heat_waves"], indent=4, sort_keys=True));
```

I have this error message:

`print(json.dumps(data[0]["heat_waves"], indent=4, sort_keys=True));
KeyError: 0`

So, my final question is:

## How can I access these nodes without writing them in raw?

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to address elements by key but with index then you can do

```
>>> import json;
>>> 
>>> data = [ ];
>>> filename = "Database.json";
>>> with open(filename,'r') as json_data:
...      data = json.load(json_data)
>>> data.values()[0]['heat_waves']
5
>>>
```